# Align struct to cache lines in Rust

Tags: rust

Assuming I wanted to (ab)use cache coherency to do lock free reads like [FaRM](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/nsdi14/nsdi14-paper-dragojevic.pdf), would it be enough to have a struct with a single 64 byte array as data to guarantee that on an architecture with 64 byte cache lines each struct would occupy exactly one cache line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that wouldn't guarantee that the alignment was a cache line.

[RFC 1358](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1358-repr-align.html) added the concept of `#[repr(align)]`, allowing the programmer to specify alignment requirements. This attribute was stabilized in [Rust 1.25](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1250-2018-03-29).

For your specific case, you'd use it like:

```
#[repr(align(64))]
struct Foo {
    value: u8,
}
```

Comment: I am confusing the size of the array with the size of the type. I guess there aren't any 64 byte simd types.

Comment: There's [AVX512](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512). Not sure if Rust supports it yet.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson: Rust doesn't have SIMD types yet. It's a big topic of discussions, lots of people are waiting for them (and the instructions that go with them) but there are many different needs/expectations/wants so it's taking a long time to converge...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, I'm following the discussions.  :-)  But there is [some unstable `#[repr(simd)]`](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/08/simd-in-rust/) support on nightlies, as far as I am aware.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson: To be honest, though, I'm not quite clear on the exact effect of applying `#[repr(simd)]`. Does it somehow use the size as alignment?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I think so, but that's only an assumption; I haven't checked.