# Memory layout, alignment, and deallocation

Tags: rust

Recently, I wanted to allocate a vector of `u64`s aligned to a 128-byte boundaries so I could use AVX512F functions. My first pass of a function to copy any `Vec<u64>` to an aligned `Vec<u64>`:

```rust
fn copy_to_aligned(inp: Vec<u64>) -> Vec<u64> {
    // note: when the returned vec is freed, the alignment / layout information
    //       will be lost. The internal memory will be freed using the alignment
    //       of a u64.
    let aligned_layout = Layout::from_size_align(inp.len() * size_of::<u64>(), 128)
        .unwrap();
    let new_vec = unsafe {
        let new_vec_mem = alloc_zeroed(aligned_layout) as *mut u64;
        copy_nonoverlapping(inp.as_ptr(), new_vec_mem, inp.len());
        Vec::from_raw_parts(new_vec_mem, inp.len(), inp.len())
    };

    return new_vec;
}
```

I now realize that this code is wrong: while the new vector is created with aligned memory and the appropriate content, when the new vector is dropped, [the memory will be de-allocated with the alignment of `u64`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.4.0/src/alloc/raw_vec.rs.html#425). The documentation for [`from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.from_raw_parts) mentions this pitfall as well.

**1) Why does the alignment of an allocation matter when I am freeing that allocation?** For example, in C, I can free any pointer by simply calling `free` -- the alignment of the allocation is irrelevant. What is special about Rust's allocator that it needs to know the alignment?

**2) What is the correct way to allocate this aligned vector?** Should I use a boxed slice? Write my own struct with a custom `Drop` implementation that gets the alignment right? [Other sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180121/how-do-i-allocate-a-vecu8-that-is-aligned-to-the-size-of-the-cache-line) suggest creating a struct and specifying the alignment, and then making a `Vec` of those structs (causing the de-allocation to use the right layout). But even with `repr(C)`, this won't ensure that all of my `u64`s are nice and densely packed next to each other, will it? I imagine arbitrary padding could be added to the struct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to figure this out with some help from Rust Discord users `svr` and `seri`.

Essentially, the allocator for the Rust API assumes that a `Layout` is provided for both allocation and deallocation. That means that the memory allocator gets to know the requested alignment of an allocation at deallocation time. You can find the API [in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.9.0/book/custom-allocators.html).

This API *could* be used to do something like keeping memory allocated to different alignments in different pools. As it turns out, the *current* default implementation [doesn't take advantage of this information during deallocation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f6fe99c798cb65280a9a56f442b371adcb7b8aa2/src/libstd/sys/unix/alloc.rs), but this could change in the future.

Currently, the best (only?) way to allocate a vector of `u64`s aligned to an N-byte boundary is to create a struct with one alignment's worth of u64's as fields, and then use the align hint, as described here: [How do I allocate a Vec<u8> that is aligned to the size of the cache line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180121/how-do-i-allocate-a-vecu8-that-is-aligned-to-the-size-of-the-cache-line?noredirect=1&lq=1)